# What does MANPATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH mean in Linux?

Tags: environment-variables, paths

What does MANPATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH mean in Linux ? What are the uses of these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [MANPATH](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/intro-linux.html). See "2.3.2. The man pages". MANPATH is the path to the manual pages.
- [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html). See "3.3.1. LD_LIBRARY_PATH".

  > In Linux, the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH is a colon-separated set of directories where libraries should be searched for first, before the standard set of directories; this is useful when debugging a new library or using a nonstandard library for special purposes. The environment variable LD_PRELOAD lists shared libraries with functions that override the standard set, just as /etc/ld.so.preload does. These are implemented by the loader /lib/ld-linux.so. I should note that, while LD_LIBRARY_PATH works on many Unix-like systems, it doesn't work on all; for example, this functionality is available on HP-UX but as the environment variable SHLIB_PATH, and on AIX this functionality is through the variable LIBPATH (with the same syntax, a colon-separated list).

Answer (score -1):

This is an environment variable which stores the paths for the user defined libraries, first this environment variable will be checked for the libraries before going to the standard library paths available.